# React: How to refresh a component with onClick using hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, onclick, use-state

I'm pretty new on this.

As an exercise I did an App that renders images of cats when clicking on a button (the images are from an API and that works fine).

My idea was to make the button refresh new images when pressed, and I know I have to be using hooks, but I'm not sure if I should use useState, setState or something else.

Here is the code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { CatsGrid } from "./components/CatsGrid";

const RandomCatApp = () => {
  return (
    <div className="catContainer">
      <h1>Random kittens</h1>

      <button onClick={'Some code here'} className="catBtn">
        Generate random kitten
      </button>

      <CatsGrid />
    </div>
  );
};

export default RandomCatApp;
```

The button must refresh  component to show new images from the API.
CatsGrid component works fine, I just tested it. My problem is with the "onClick" and useState or something else in the code above.

Here is CatsGrid component just in case:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export const CatsGrid = () => {
  const [imagen, setImagen] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getCats();
  }, []);

  const getCats = async () => {
    const url = "someApiKey";

    const resp = await fetch(url);

    const data = await resp.json();

    const catImg = data.map((img) => {
      return {
        id: img.id,
        url: img.url,
      };
    });

    setImagen(catImg);
  };

  return (
    <div className="imgContainer">
      {imagen.map(({ id, url }) => (
        <img className="catImg" key={id} src={url} alt="" />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Other than you should really be using a functional update to toggle the `show` state (`setShow(show => !show)`) I see no issue with this code. If by clicking twice you mean to toggle the view back to the `CatsGrid` then I would expect that be the designed behavior. Can you describe more precisely the issue, and what you expect the behavior to be?

Comment: @DrewReese thank you for replying, and sorry for not being clear. I'm gonna explain it in other way.

The code above works fine, but not in the way I wanted to be. When I press the button, first the images are erased and I have to press the button again to bring new ones. The idea was to refresh new images with a single click.

I just edited my post so it can be better explained.

Comment: I see, how/where are you generating the images? Does `CatsGrid` handle that?

Comment: Yes, it's a simple fetch api

Comment: Ok, so if I understand correctly, you want to click a button in the parent and get `CatsGrid` to fetch new images? Can you share your `CatsGrid` component? There are likely several options but I'd like to see what you are working with.

Comment: Sure. I just updated the post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, assuming the `fetch` in `getCats` in `CatsGrid` always returns a new set of data then I suggest just using a React key on the `CatsGrid` component so React will unmount/mount a new instance of it. When the React key changes React will interpret this as a *new* component to render.

```
const RandomCatApp = () => {
  const [catsKey, setCatsKey] = React.useState(0);
  return (
    <div className="catContainer">
      <h1>Random kittens</h1>

      <button
        onClick={() => setCatsKey(key => key + 1)}
        className="catBtn"
      >
        Generate random kitten
      </button>

      <CatsGrid key={catsKey} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I spent 4 hours trying to figure this out! Thank you so much this worked for me! I used keys in Flutter and I didn't expect to need them in React. Wow!